# Connecting portable generator with L6-20P to house with L14-30R

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, generator

I have been spinning my wheels reading on this trying to figure out what to do.

I have a 5000W Portal generator that is NG bonded
The generator has a 250V output with a L6-20R connector.

I have a Square D generator interlock installed by an licensed electrician
The power inlet on my house is an L14-30R.

I bought a generator cable but both ends are L14-30 (4 prong).
I bought a L6-20P connector and plan on installing this on Plug side of the generator cable (i'd cut off the 4 prong).

The question is how I wire the new L6-20P on the cable:
The L14-30R has X,Y,Neutral and a Ground.
The L6-20P has X,Y and G.

When I put the L6-20P on the end of the generator cable, should I hook G of L6-20P up to G of L14-30R? This would give me two NG points in the system since the generator is NG bound.

The other option is to not connect the G to anything and just hook up X/Y?

Thanks for any help,

- Mike

Comment: Do you have any 110V or 120V loads in your house, or are all the loads 240V?

Comment: just plan on running only 110v when generator is connected. I'd flip air handlers, hvac off at breaker before flipping to generator

Comment: Ok, so you're **really, really gonna need** that neutral, otherwise you will have an "open neutral" situation and your appliances will blow up.   The 6-20 lacks a neutral.   Now you need to consult with the generator manufacturer and find out whether they support what you need: **split-phase power**, and how to cable that if they do.

Comment: I guess how does this exist then? i was just trying to basically wire what this thing is: https://www.amazon.com/NEMA-L6-30P-L15-30R-Plug-Adapter/dp/B00DM7F0IA

Comment: Look at the seller, "sold by and ships from <not Amazon>", that is the **Amazon Marketplace**, which is akin to eBay or AliExpress.  There, *somebody* will sell you *anything*. It's the wild west. I'm not saying it can't be done, I'm saying only the manufacturer can say whether or how they support this.  If it's a no-name generator, you might have to take it apart and see how it's wired, and add that to your question.

Comment: What is the make and model of the generator?

Comment: Yea I know what you mean about that. I did call support but the person was not sure and directed me to a reseller of who I have not been able to be in contact with. It's a Coleman/Powermate powerbase 5000W generator. Non-GFCI (just a circuit breakers) with 2 standard 110V receptacles and 1 L6-20R (240V).

Comment: Apparently they make several models which meet that description, and the one I spot-checked had an L14-20 and stated vey plainly that it supported 120/240 right on page 2 of the manual.   If your manual says 120/240, then this can be done. http://www.powermate.com/productmanuals.php?cat_id=3 Otherwise we'd need to see how the receptacles (120 and 240) are wired on the back.

Comment: Thanks @Harper, definitely appreciate guidance. I was just out there disassembling because I think the best thing to do might be to replace the L6-20 with a 14-20 introducing a neutral. The main output wires of the generator has 2 black (hot) and two (neutrals). One black goes to one breaker, the other to a 2nd breaker. The blacks then go to to L6-20. The whites feed to neutral on standard 110v Rs. Ground is jumpered on the 110 from ground to neutral. I'll remove the jumpers as well making it a floating neutral

Comment: Its sounds like you're fine then, connect those 2 neutrals (both) to both the neutral on the NEMA 14-20 and the neutral on the NEMA 5, then tie generator chassis to all the ground pins, then finally tie neutral to ground somewhere Don't let any neutrals be disconnected or you'll have lost neutral problems, your two 120V sides will total 240 but they won't be 120 each!

Comment: Ah you think i should keep the neutral bonded to ground?

Comment: Yes, since it's already so on the 120V plug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to come back here since there was no answer posted. Appreciate @Harper's help, I wish they would have put an answer so I could accept!

So I ended up buying an L14-30R and replacing the L6-20R in the generator. I wired neutral over to the 240V and wired up the two hots to it. I wired ground over to one of the 120V that had ground on it but I REMOVED the jumper from ground to neutral.

Since I only have a interlock and a inlet plug for the house, neutral is NOT switched over to the generator. If you have a proper transfer switch neutral MIGHT be switched to the generator. Since neutral was not switched, I'm using the house's NG bond and therefore I want neutral to float in the generator. If you do this, you should label the generator as Neutral floating in case you sell it or need reminding.

Everything worked well when I was running on generator power for 3 or 4 days after an ice storm.